# Server's quotation mark (") appears as "â" in iOS app

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8

I am currently writing an iOS app that reads data from a PHP `echo`. After much hassle escaping each character I resorted to PHP function `UTF8_Encode`.

This seemed to work great, however when I have a quotation mark (`"`) in the output, it appears as `â` in the app.

---

The code for sending the feed from the PHP app is:

```
echo (UTF8_encode($variable));
```

---

The code for consuming this feed in the iOS app is:

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"thisisalink"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSData *returnData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *strResult = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: Please share your code for consuming this PHP feed in your app.

Comment: echo (UTF8_encode($variable));

The variable being long text containing mixed symbols amongst text.

Comment: Sorry the code for consuming is:

    NSString    *urlString      = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://thisisalink"];

    
    NSURL       *url            = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSData      *returnData     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString    *strResult      = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

Comment: Yes, they are. The text is written in word first, before being pasted into a database.

Comment: Many Thanks, I will be looking at converting them to UTF8 characters within the PHP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seeing `â` stems from the use of curly quotation marks (e.g. `“` rather than `"`) and some disconnect between the character set encoding being transmitted by the server and the character set encoding being processed by the iOS app.

I can't reproduce your problem precisely, but I can simulate it with the following in the process of sending a response that is simply `“x”` by deliberately misusing `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` instead of `NSUTF8StringEncoding`:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding]; // this won't work
NSLog(@"data = %@, string = %@", data, string);
```

Instead of the expected `“x”` response that my server sent, that generates the following output:

```
data = <e2809c78 e2809d>, results = âxâ
```

those first three bytes (`0xe2809c`) represent the opening quote character, the `0x78` represents the letter `x`, and the last three bytes (`0xe2809d`) represent the closing quote character. Bottom line, as you can see, Objective-C doesn't know what to make of this.

There are a couple of solutions:

1. Strip these extended unicode characters from your server's response.
2. Make sure that the server's response's character set matches that of the parsing response on the client.
3. Alternatively, you can use a file format that does this conversion for you. For example I've used the PHP `json_encode` function, which takes care of converting the character set:

   ```
   echo json_encode(array("response" => $variable));
   ```

   I then used the following Objective-C code to parse this in iOS:

   ```
   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
   NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
   ```

   That reports a JSON response that looks like:

   ```
   {"response":"\u201cx\u201d"}
   ```

   You can then parse that JSON like so:

   ```
   NSError *error = nil;
   NSDictionary *results = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];

   if (!error)
       NSLog(@"%@", results[@"response"]);
   else
       NSLog(@"Unable to parse: error = %@", error);
   ```

   That reports, as you probably originally intended, the following:

   ```
   “x”
   ```

Personally, when my server is sending data to be parsed by my app, I always use a format designed for machine-to-machine interfaces, such as JSON or XML. This lets me put structured responses together, easier to report errors, solves many text formatting issues, etc.